# Is data sent to Google when using the Google Visualisation API?

Tags: security, google-api, google-visualization

I am developing a web app for a client and I want to use the Google API's to draw some nice graphs.

The client has some sensitive data and has raised some concerns about security, specifically, they do not want their data "going to Google".

There are 2 options or API's for generating charts. The Chart API, where you build a URL and submit to Google so that it can generate a graph image - obviously the client data IS going to Google so this option is a no no.

The second option is to use the Visualisation API. As far as I am aware, the code to generate the visualisation is downloaded from Google, but the data used to build the output never leaves the browser, and therefore is "safe" to use with sensitive data. Is this an accurate description?

I have looked through the Google API documentation to try and answer my question but cant seem to find a definitive answer.

Please advise.

Comment: Please, review the new answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311704/is-data-sent-to-google-when-using-the-google-visualisation-api/19811513#19811513 .I think the accepted question is wrong actually. Thanks

Comment: In case anybody else is looking for an open source, secure solution, you may want to check out  graphael: http://g.raphaeljs.com

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. There is a Data Policy section in the Google documentation for each type of visualisation, Area Chart, Line Chart, Annotated Time Line etc. For the visualisations I'm interested in using the Data Policy section states:

> **All code and data are processed and rendered in the browser. No data is sent to any server.**

Guess I didn't see the wood for the trees!

Comment: this depends on the visualisation, see comment below by same person

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about using google's API, then I'd suggest you use a different visualization API.

As @Rook said, google logs everything.

The mitigating factor here is context.  If the data you are sending has no context, then I wouldn't worry about it.  It could be charting chicken house expansions for all they know.

However, if your charts do include contextual data that can be traced to something important, then you'll need to have something installed locally to do the rendering for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/security_privacy you can see **actual** terms and conditions:

> **A Note About Security and Data Privacy**
>
> Google maintains a gallery of useful and fun charts, some of which
>   were created by us, and others that were created by third-parties. All
>   charts depend on linked JavaScript libraries, and some might send
>   chart data from the browser to another location for preprocessing.
>   Google-Authored Charts   All Google-authored charts are developed with
>   privacy and security considerations in mind. All Google chart
>   documentation pages include a data policy section that describes
>   whether a chart sends any chart data from the page.

As you can see, it's not clear. It's necesary to review documentation periodically (not only terms and conditions), because terms and conditions are few specific.

Comment: The accepted answer is still correct as far as I'm concerned. Please see the Data Policy section in the documentation for each chart type in the API. Almost every chart (with the exception of Maps and Geo Charts) within the API process the data within the browser. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Data_Policy

Comment: Sorry for the incovenince. Do you have reviewed all data policies? How do you grant it won't change in the future without previous advice in terms and conditions? How could your potential clients know if the data will be sent to Google in the future without previos advice? I think my response complement yours and actually both are true. Please, consider includen a mention about google terms and conditions. Thanks.

Comment: The quote here refers to the "gallery of useful and fun charts", not to using  the Google Charts library in your own projects.

Comment: I think the meaning of "gallery of useful and fun charts" refers to "library" not to the online gallery. This is the reason they include this in the agreement. So it should appy also in your own projects.