# Does the Google Chart API send your chart data to google?

Tags: google-visualization

Does anyone know whether the [Google Chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/index) sends the raw data, used to generate the charts and visualisations, to Google?
In other words are the charts and visualisations generated by Google's servers or are they generated locally by the Chart API's Javascript libraries.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311704/is-data-sent-to-google-when-using-the-google-visualisation-api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about the charts generated from a url (the chart api) then from the FAQ

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq#chartapi

> What is the difference between the Google Chart API and the Google
>   Visualization API?
>
> The Chart API provides a simple way to create image charts of various
>   kinds by sending a formatted URL that includes both the ***data and
>   chart configuration options*** to a Google server. The Chart API
>   includes a closed set of charts with various options. The Chart API
>   datasets are limited to the size of a URL (roughly 2K).

For the Visualisation API it depends on the chart/visualisation, see the Data Policy for example this one for the line chart

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Data_Policy

Comment: It seems like the short answer is: Yes. The library does send data to a central server, unlike all the other JavaScript libraries for plotting. Am I right?